# how update shopping cart codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, cart

*fisrt my english's bad i hope you can understand my question and help me*

```
foreach($data as $row)     
{ 
    echo(" 
         <tr class='info'> 
                 <td>'" .$row['id']. "'</td> 
                 <td>'" .$row['name']."'</td> 
                 <td>'" .$row[''] ."</td> 
                 <td><input type='text' value='".$row['qty']. "' size='5' class='qty' name='qty'> 
                 <input type='hidden' value=".$row['rowid']." name='rowid'></td> 
                 <td>'".$row['subtotal']."'</td> 
         </tr> ");                 
}
```

when i edit qty of item,it's just last row change
now i wan't if i edit any row it's will change

Comment: I think that you have a clear idea of what you're wanting to do and what's actually happening, but I can't understand from your explanation what those are. Can you please explain your question again and use more detail so it's clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use

```
foreach($this->cart->contents() as $row){
   echo'   
        <tr class="info"> 
                <td>'.$row["id"].'</td> 
                <td>'.$row["name"].'</td> 
                <td>$row[""]</td> 
                <td><input type="text" value="'.$row["qty"].'" size="5" class="qty" name="qty"> 
                <input type="hidden" value="'.$row["rowid"].'" name="rowid"></td> 
                <td>'.$row["subtotal"].'</td> 
        </tr> ';

}
```

Comment: nothing changes
this is my controller

`function update() {
  $sl=$this->input->post('qty');
  $idrow = $this->input->post('rowid');
  
  $data = array(
   'rowid' => $idrow,
   'qty' => $sl
  );`